# WPF MVVM Entity Framework. Проблема с валидацией

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Делаю CRUD на WPF MVVM. Контрол RadGridView но это в принципе не важно. С командами разобрался.  Застрял с валидацией..

**Это моя viewModel**

```
public class DirectoryViewModel : TurnikamBaseModel
{
    private TurnikamEntities _dataContext;

    private ObservableCollection<TBL_SEX> tbl_sex;

    public ObservableCollection<TBL_SEX> Tbl_sex
    {
        get { return tbl_sex; }
        set { tbl_sex = value; }
    }

    private TBL_SEX selectedSex;

    public TBL_SEX SelectedSex
    {
        get { return selectedSex; }
        set
        {
            if (this.selectedSex != value)
            {
                selectedSex = value;
                ((RelayCommand)this.SexDeleteCommand).IsEnabled = true;
                this.OnPropertyChanged(() => this.selectedSex);
            }
        }
    }

    public DirectoryViewModel()
    {
        _dataContext = new TurnikamEntities();
        tbl_sex = new ObservableCollection<TBL_SEX>(_dataContext.TBL_SEX);

        sexSave = new RelayCommand(SexSave) { IsEnabled = true };
        sexAdd = RadGridViewCommands.BeginInsert;
        sexDelete = new RelayCommand(SexDelete) { IsEnabled = false };
    }

    ICommand sexSave;
    ICommand sexAdd;
    ICommand sexDelete;

    public ICommand SexSaveCommand
    {
        get { return sexSave; }
        set { sexSave = value; }
    }

    private void SexSave()
    {
        _dataContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public ICommand SexAddCommand
    {
        get { return sexAdd; }
    }

    public ICommand SexDeleteCommand
    {
        get { return sexDelete; }
    }

    private void SexDelete()
    {
        if (SelectedSex != null)
        {
            if (SelectedSex.SexGUID!=Guid.Empty)
            {
                this._dataContext.TBL_SEX.DeleteObject(SelectedSex);
            }
            Tbl_sex.Remove(SelectedSex);
            OnPropertyChanged("Tbl_sex");
        }
        else
        {
            ((RelayCommand)this.SexDeleteCommand).IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: А что валидировать нужно?

Comment: Валидировать нужно то что вводим в ячейки грида. Проверить на пустоту, на максимальную длину и тд. Без MVVM в этом ничего сложного нет. А так даже не знаю с чего начать. Entity Framework тоже мешает немного но уже назад пути нет) В инете ничего гормального не нашел..

Comment: Хм. А причём тут EF? При использовании MVVM у вас UI видит не Entity, а VM-объекты.

Comment: Так как мне добавить валидацию. EF классы сделать Partial? Просто не понимаю как по правильному сделать это.

Comment: Вас валидация в EF или WPF интересует?

Comment: В WPF. я делаю CRUD в RadGridView. С командами разобрался. Теперь валидацию надо сделать в гриде. Если честно вообще плохо представляю как это сделать.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28615034/wpf-mvvm-textbox-validation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Собственно, есть 3 (насколько мне известно) варианта валидации в WPF:

**1. Валидация на исключениях.**

Самый простой способ. Выглядит примерно так:

XAML

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding String1, ValidateOnExceptions=True}"/>
```

ViewModel

```
class SomeObject
{
    ...
    public string String1
    {
        get { return _string1; }
        set
        {
            if (_string1 != value)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_string1))
                    throw new ArgumentException("value");

                _string1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("String1");
            }
        }
    }
    private string _string1;
}
```

**2. Валидация на правилах.**

[Пример на msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Если коротко, то создается определенное правило (наследник ValidationRule), которое используется тэге Binding в XAML разметке.

**3. Валидация на источнике данных (или как-то так).**

[Пример на msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909868%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Можно использовать атрибуты из DataAnnotations или описывать кастомные правила валидации. ViewModel должна реализовать интерфейс `IDataErrorInfo`. Пример с использованием атрибута `Required`:

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding String1, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

ViewModel

```
public class SomeObject : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    ...

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false, ErrorMessage="Hello, world!")]
    public string String1
    {
        get { return _string1; }
        set
        {
            if (_string1 != value)
            {
                _string1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("String1");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _string1;

    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
    {
        get { return Validate(propertyName); }
    }

    private string Validate(string propertyName)
    {
        var value = GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(this, null);
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        var context = new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = propertyName };

        if (!Validator.TryValidateProperty(value, context, results))
        {
            return results.First().ErrorMessage;
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

**UPD**

Я бы не советовал смешивать валидацию Model и ViewModel. Поэтому для тех моделей, которые выставляются наружу и которые нужно каким-то образом проверять имеет смысл завести ViewModel. Реализацию `IDataErrorInfo` можно взять из примера выше и засунуть ее в базовую ViewModel:

```
class TblSexVm : SomeObject //(читать BaseViewModel)
{
    TBL_SEX Model{get; private set;}

    public TblSexVm(TBL_SEX model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false, ErrorMessage="Hello, world!")]
    public string SexName
    {
        get { return Model.SexName; }
        set 
        {
            if (Model.SexName != value)
            {
                Model.SexName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SexName");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: До меня не доходит как использовать 3-й вариант в моем случаи. вот у меня есть тейбл в базе TBL_SEX{ Guid sexGUID; string SexName}. я создал private ObservableCollection<TBL_SEX> tbl_sex; где у меня будет валидация?

Comment: Обновил ответ. Валидация будет во ViewModel-обертке над TBL_SEX. Соответственно и наружу будет выставлены не объекты TBL_SEX, а объекты TblSexVm.

Comment: ObservableCollection<TblSexVm>

Comment: `tbl_sex = new ObservableCollection<TblSexVm>(как заполнить?)`

Comment: `tbl_sex = new ObservableCollection<TblSexVm>(_dataContext.TBL_SEX.Select(_ => new TblSexVm(_));` а потом следишь, чтоб добавление и удаление происходило в обеих коллекциях: tbl_sex и _dataContext.TBL_SEX.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23318/discussion-between-zirrama-and-vlad).

Comment: Спасибо большое. Вроде заработало)

Comment: Когда в таблице есть данные выдает ошибку : The underlying provider failed on Open.  В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Не знаю. Ищите.