# Валидация данных

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня возникла такая проблема: мне нужно чтобы если в TextBox ошибка, то кнопка становилась неактивной. Проблема в том что TextBox-ов таких несколько. Я пробовал делать обычную валидацию на исключениях и несколько флагов для каждого из полей обозначающих их валидность и биндить кнопку. Но это очень муторно. А если еще добавлять поля? Все новые флаги создавать? Ужасно неудобно и коряво. Подскажите пожалуйста какой то более красивый способ.

Comment: Посмотрите на [этот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420203/wpf-mvvm-entity-framework-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9) вопрос.

Comment: @Vlad я прекрасно представляю себе механизмы валидации. Не надо мне вот эти очевидные вещи совать. И конкретно ту тему в частности я уже видел раньше. Она не решает мою проблему.

Comment: Тогда непонятно, в чем проблема? Засовываете в VM все свойства, которые нужно валидировать, вешаете соответствующие атрибуты и привязываете их к TextBox. Доступность команды связываете с наличием ошибок валидации. При добавлении новых полей никаких  дополнительных телодвижений не потребуется.

Comment: @Vlad в кнопке проблема. Исключительно в ней. Она должна быть не активна если есть ошибки ввода в TextBox-ах.

Comment: Так привяжите CanExecute команды, которая привязывается к кнопке, к наличию ошибок валидации.

Comment: @Vlad зачем еще CanExecute? о_О Я привязываю IsEnabled. Вот о том и речь что нужно знать есть ли ошибки валидации. Если бы это можно было как то просто получить то вопрос бы отпал сам собой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы используете MVVM, то все довольно просто. Делаете валидацию на источнике данных. Свойства с ошибками валидации собираете в список. Если список пустой, то ошибок нет, а значит можно нажимать на кнопку. Вот пример VM:

```
public sealed class MainVm : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    // перечень свойств с ошибками
    private readonly HashSet<string> propertiesWithErrors = new HashSet<string>();

    // метод валидации свойства
    private string Validate(string propertyName)
    {
        var value = GetType()
            .GetProperty(propertyName)
            .GetValue(this, null);

        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        var context = new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = propertyName };

        if (!Validator.TryValidateProperty(value, context, results))
        {
            // добавляем информацию о том, что это свойство содержит ошибку
            propertiesWithErrors.Add(propertyName);
            return results.First().ErrorMessage;
        }

        // удаляем информацию об ошибке в свойстве
        propertiesWithErrors.Remove(propertyName);
        return string.Empty;
    }
    // фамилия (бросает PropertyChanged)
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    // имя (бросает PropertyChanged)
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // команда, которая привязывется к кнопке. Допустим, применить какие-либо изменения
    public ICommand ApplyCommand { get; }

    // реализация IDataErrorInfo
    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
    string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
    {
        get { return Validate(propertyName); }
    }
    // ------

    public MainVm()
    {
        // создаем команду
        // первый аргумент Execute (ничего не делаем)
        // второй аргумент CanExecute (true, если нет свойств с ошибками)
        ApplyCommand = new RelayCommand(o => { }, o => !propertiesWithErrors.Any());
    }
```

RelayCommand можно стащить [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468791/wpf-icommand-mvvm-implementation). В представлении все еще проще. Привязываем свойства к TextBox, а кнопку к команде.

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainVm/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Surname, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Command="{Binding ApplyCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**UPD**

Нет, атрибут Required никакого отношения к INotifyPropertyChanged не имеет. 
Свойтсво, на самом деле, должно выглядеть вот так:

```
public string Name 
{ 
    get { return name; } 
    set
    {
        if (name != value)
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        }
    }
} 
private string name;

private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    var tmp = PropertyChanged;
    if (tmp != null)
    {
        tmp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Атрибут Required говорит о том, что у данного свойства должно быть установлено значение, отличное от null и string.Empty.

Comment: че за атрибут Required?

Comment: Из System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Comment: я не понял, оно что само вызывает PropertyChanged??? Т.е. это как бы аналог Fody.PropertyChanged от .NET?

Comment: @DarkByte, что оно?

Comment: ну то что этот атрибут сам вызывает PropertyChanged при изменении свойства?

Comment: я вот чего не могу понять: как кнопка то неактивной становится??? У вас же нет никакого биндинга к IsEnabled. И вообще это свойство нигде не затрагивается. Так как же так выходит?

Comment: Ага понял, это засчет CanExecute. Я просто только только разбираюсь в этих командах. И еще не знал что CanExecute так влияет.

Comment: короче спасибо огромное!!! Я еще немного поразбираюсь в этом если будут вопросы отпишусь, но кажется это реально то что надо!!!

Comment: Погодите погодите... Но ведь это работает!!! Без указания OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name))! Т.е. вручную не приходится обновлять свойство, это же огромный плюс! О чем вы вообще?

Comment: @DarkByte, это будет работать при установке значений из представления. Но если вы захотите установить значение внутри VM, то представление не сможет отреагировать на изменения при отстутствии события.

Comment: ааа печально... Но с другой стороны мне и не надо в данном случае устанавливать из VM их.

Comment: появился первый вопрос: если я хочу еще добавить условий, то куда мне их вставить? Ну скажем не просто не пустая строка, а во первых double, во вторых диапазон ему задать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38546/discussion-between-vlad-and-dark-byte).

Answer (score 1):

Можно для кнопки добавить поле Count, если textbox поменял свой статус на неправильное, то +1 к count, если он поменял с неправильного на правильное, то -1 count. (Здесь надо аккуратно сделать, чтобы поле добавляло\отменяло только при смене статуса на противоположное, т.е. чтобы интервал значения count был от 0 до количества textbox.) Соответственно, как только count обратился в 0 - кнопка работает.

Comment: вот я уже и сам до этого додумался. Ну, если более элегантного решения никто не предложит, наверное так и сделаю.

Comment: можно с событиями сделать

Comment: в смысле с событиями?

Comment: Тут еще проблема в том что приходится объявлять биндинг всегда к текстовому полю. Потому что инкрементировать счетчик надо и в случае неверной конвертации. Ужас конечно как неудобно все равно...

Comment: Например если у меня поле double, но все равно придется текстовое для биндинга объявлять, чтобы в сеттере проверить еще и конвертацию в double. Это ведь тоже ошибка...

Comment: кстати говоря нет, нефига этот способ с количеством ошибок не сработает... А все потому что в какой момент вы предлагает декрементировать? Если в сеттере все хорошо? Так если подряд несколько раз не будет ошибок он его будет каждый раз декрементировать и в минус вообще уйдет... Нет, это неверный подход... Даже хуже чем просто кучу флагов делать.

Comment: так я говорил про этот случай. Речь о том что у textbox есть состояние (верно, неверно) и изменение идет только если переключаются состояния

Comment: т.е. вы предлагаете одновременно и флаги использовать и счетчик ошибок? Нафига? Еще больше кода?