# Расширение функционала класса валидатора

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, uwp, валидация

Приветствую!

Необходимо произвести несложную проверку введенных в несколько `TextBox` символов :
во первых что введены целые числа, и во вторых, что введенные числа находятся в определенном интервале. Для этого решил написать свой простенький класс валидатор и подключить к разметке. Собственно XAML :

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabledTextBoxs}">
    <TextBox.Text>
       <Binding Path="Property">
          <Binding.ValidationRules>
             <correct:MinMaxFormat_Correct Min="1" Max="6" />
           </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

И класс Валидатор :

```
class MinMaxFormat_Correct : ValidationRule
    {
        public int Min { get; set; }
        public int Max { get; set; }

        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            var str = value as string;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(false, "string is Empty or Equals null");
            }
            try
            {
                var integ = Convert.ToInt32(str);
                if (integ <= Max && integ >= Min)
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(true, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(false, "Property must be a minimum 1 and maximum 6");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(false, ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Все правильно - при вводе строки или некорректного числа текст бокс подсвечивается красным. Но проблема в том, что класс `MinMaxFormat_Correct` не имеет влияния на `VM` модель и его поведение ограничено простым подсветом. Иными словами - нужно не только подсвечивать красным текстбокс с ошибкой но и запрещать дальнейшие действия пользователя - например внутри `VM` модели есть `bool` проперти к которому привязано свойство `IsEnabled` некоторой кнопки, которая будет обрабатывать введенные значения и если валидатор отловил исключение то `bool= false` и тогда не придется в обработчике самой кнопки писать кучу `if-else` а сразу начинать обработку данных. Можно ли что то подобное осуществить и если можно то как ?

Comment: Такой вариант не подойдет: [клик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/514330)?

Comment: Вот еще: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/728835/218063

Comment: @Vlad В том примере класс валидатор вообще не используется. Получается что расширить его функционал никак нельзя ?

Comment: Правила валидации прописываются и используются в разметке. Разметка ничего не знает о моделях представления. Если нужна валидация от данных, то используется `IDataErrorInfo`.

Comment: @Vlad А о представлении разметка должна знать ? Может просто скрыть кнопку ? Просто, зачем тогда правила валидации если они не на что по сути не влияют - ввел что то неправильное = ничего, страшного выделим красным но работу можно продолжать.

Comment: Так `ValidationRule` устанавливает присоединенное свойство `ValidationError.HasError` в `true`. Можно воспользоваться им для определения видимости кнопки, например.

Comment: @Vlad  Подскажите тогда как привязаться к  `ValidationError.HasError` ?

Comment: @Vlad Как я понимаю, для этого нужно каждому текст боксу установить : `NotifyOnValidationError=True` и сделать биндинг кнопки ?

Comment: Не знаю. Сейчас попробую написать пример (если раньше этого никто не сделает). Я на практике с этим способом валидации не сталкивался.

Comment: @Vlad есть еще способ - обрабатывать событие  `Validation.Error` в code-behind но это на крайний случай - бехайнд не должен лезть в разметку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот пример того, как можно скрыть кнопку.

Создаем какое-нибудь правило:

```
public sealed class MyRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var str = value as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Error!");
        }

        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
}
```

В разметку помещаем текстовое поле с кнопкой. К текстовому полю привязываем созданное правило. Доступностью кнопки управляем через триггер, в котором проверяем наличие ошибок у текстового поля.

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Name="textBox">
        <Binding Path="Text" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:MyRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox>
    <Button Content="Submit">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBox, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

**UPD**

Для нескольких `TextBox` можно использовать `MultiDataTrigger`:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBox, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBox2, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

Comment: Я вижу здесь привязка к только одному текстбоксу. В вопросе описана ситуация для нескольких.

Comment: @Сергей, обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Хорошее решение.