# Как при помощи паттерна mvvm c# wpf обработать событие?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Пытаюсь реализовать приложение по всем правилам mvvm, и я столкнулся с проблемой обработки события. Для примера, присутствует текстовое поле, к которому привязано событие `TextChanged`, но по правилам обработка метода происходит в viewmodel.

Comment: используйте привязки, забудьте про события

Comment: Я немного не могу понять, как именно при помощи привязки возможно осуществить динамическую проверку текстового поля, или, допустим менять контент текстового поля, при наведении на него курсора.

Comment: чтобы проверять значение в текстовом поле читайте [про валидацию в MVVM + WPF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420235/179763). Про наведение курсора у вас в вопросе ничего нет, потому на это я не отвечаю.

Comment: В вашем случае есть несколько вариантов по моему мнению. 1) к полю Text привязать свойство из ViewModel. При изминении текста у вас будет отрабатывать setter и там вы сможете делать то, что надо с текстом (этот вариант для изменения текста). 2) Если надо валидировать как-то значение, то @tym32167 подсказал, что надо сделать

Comment: Большое спасибо, пойду пробовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализуешь интерфейс     INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string text;

    public string Text
    {
        get => text;
        set
        {
            text = value;
            //обрабатываешь здесь значение из элемента
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

Делаешь в xaml привязку

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="100" Height="100"/>
</Grid>
```

И не нужно реализовывать никаких команд для данного события